# PowerPoint 2007 - how to play movies simultaneously within a slide?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I have six small clips (.wmv) inside a PowerPoint 2007 slide (for Windows). If I set all the videos to play automatically only the first one starts playing.

Any ideas how to make them play simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *Animation* tab, select *Custom Animation*. Select all your videos, and choose *Add Effects* -> Media (something similar) -> *Play*.

Once you see the play animations in the animation pane, select all of them, right click, and choose *With Previous* in the menu.

Comment: Actually this is NOT entirely correct. It will work ONLY if autoplay is selected and all animations will stat playing  start when the slide is changed.  I noticed that sometimes removing and then re-adding the animations may fix some problems with Powerpoint 2013.

Comment: It also works in Powerpoint 2016. The difference is to select all clips and then in the Animations table, click 'Play'.